# Can you explain the following SQL (postgres) code?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I asked SO for a query to find all rows in a table with a 'code' entry that is a substring of the search string, with the added condition that it appears at the end of the search string.

So a query for '12345' should return '2345', '345', '45', and '5'.

I was given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924466/4003419), which works. I have read through the documentation but still don't understand the query. Can someone please explain

```
SELECT * from yourtable
where '12345' like '%' || Code
```

Comment: See the documentation of [Postgres matching functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html), or any decent sql documentation on the `like` operator.

Comment: I've read the documentation but still don't understand, which is why I was hoping for a walkthrough of this particular query to aid my understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally a LIKE is used in the opposite way.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn LIKE '%xxx%'
```

So you check if the column matches against a fixed string with a pattern.

But the clever thing about that answer was it did the opposite.

It checks a fixed string again a pattern that's created from a column.

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE 'bar456' LIKE '%' || SomeColumn;
```

In this example, if "SomeColumn" contains the value "56"?
Then `'%' || SomeColumn` forms the string `'%56'`

So 'bar456' is like '%56', since it ends with '56'
And 'bar456' is also like '%ar456'

Comment: Much better explanation than mine: kudos!

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant documentation links you need:

1. [PostgreSQL Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html): `'12345' like '%'`
2. [PostgreSQL CONCATENATE(||) Operator](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/concatenate-operator.php): `<match> || Code`

The SQL means:

1. Fetch all columns from the table
2. *IF* column "code" is equal to `<match> + <value of "code" column>`

Comment: Thank you so much! I dont know why everyone else was so reluctant to give this simple explanation